# Why sales_order_item and quote_item being populated with configurable and simple product?

Tags: magento-2.1, sales-order, quote

Whenever I created the product item I always found that the `sales_order_item` is populated with two rows for each product for example :

`select quote_item_id,expected_delivery_time, sku,product_type from sales_order_item;`

```
+---------------+------------------------+---------------+--------------+
| quote_item_id | expected_delivery_time | sku           | product_type |
+---------------+------------------------+---------------+--------------+
|           109 | 2017-10-20 17:00:00    | WS05-L-Black  | configurable |
|           110 | NULL                   | WS05-L-Black  | simple       |
```

I have successfully add the `expected_delivery_time` using this snippet code when using :

```
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item
     */
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        ....
        if (!empty($expectedDays)){
            $deliveryTime = $this->_getPreparedDateTime($deliverDay);
            $item->setExpectedDeliveryTime($deliveryTime);
            $item->save();
        }
    }
```

But above code only set the `expected_delivery_item` for configurable `product_type` not with the simple, although it is created by the same `sku` and the same product.

Please somebody explain to me why magento 2 created two rows for every product in the `sales_order_item` and `quote_item` table?

And I found out that whenever I login to the admin panel and create my own order, the two rows become simple all of them.

Why is this different when the user create an order from the front-end site it is configurable and simple but not from the admin panel?

And the last is how do set the `expected_delivery_date` for the simple product created in the `sales_quote_item` and `quote_item` table?

Comment: I recall reading somewhere that the reason for the configurable is convenience but I agree it's weird especially since the skus are the same. As far as not getting a configurable item when the order is placed in the backend that's just inconsistent and a bug in my opinion.

As far as your specific problem, how are you obtaining $items? I believe there's a way to get allItems vs visibleItems where the former includes the configurables and the later just the simples.